# Proper way of disposing Image inside Object in Dictionary of Objects

Tags: c#, image, dictionary

I have `Dictionary<int,RPicture>` with..

```
public class RPicture
{
    public Image image;
    public string filePath;
}
```

The RPicture instances are only stored (referenced) in that Dictionary and each RPicture Image is only referenced in its one RPicture obj.

What is a right way to Dispose the Image in RPicture record in the Dictionary ?
Is removing the record with `Dict.Remove(1);` enough ?
Or, is there a better / proper solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dict.Remove(1);` will make your `RPicture` inaccessible. On the next GC run, it will be collected and eventually disposed of.

Because this is subobtimal if an object uses a significant amount of a limited resource (RAM in your case), the `IDisposable` interface (as @lightbricko mentioned) provides a way to free those resources in a repeatable way. Basically, the `IDisposable` mechanism provides a way to decouple freeing of an object's payload resources from collecting the object itself.

So if you implement `IDisposable` on your `RPicture` and then call (a sane version of) `Dispose()` on it after removing it from the dictionary, you will end up with the Object being collected later, but its payload image's resources being freed right now. I suspect, this is what you want.

```
public class RPicture: IDisposable
{
    public Image image;
    public string filePath;

    public void Dispose()
    {
       image.Dispose();
       image=null;
       filePath=null;
     }
}
```

would be a chatty but working candidate.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot for thorough explanation AND an example ! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `Dictionary` class itself won't call the object's `Dispose` method because it has no way of knowing if anything else has a reference to the object. Removing it will remove the dictionary's reference and, if you're right in saying that there are no more references, the GC will pick it up eventually.

However since `Image` implements `IDisposable`, it's a good idea to call the `Dispose` method yourself if its memory usage is high (likely with images). In that case you can get a reference to the item before removing it and then calling `Dispose` on it. (This assumes you've implemented `IDisposable` on `RPicture` as shown in Eugen's answer).

```
public void RemoveAndDisposeFromDictionary(Dictionary<int, RPicture> dict, int index)
{
    var myRImage = dict[index];              
    dict.Remove(index);
    myRImage.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [System.Drawing.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Image.aspx) implements IDisposable you should dispose it. Best practice is to make your containing class implement IDisposable and then dispose your class when no longer needed. Your implementation should in turn dispose the image by calling the Dispose method.

Comment: Thanks.  
Just to be certain: with my approach the Image woun't get Disposed (at time of the record removal) ?

Comment: No it will **not**. However when the garbage collector calls the destructor of the Image object, that destructor will dispose the managed resource (but that might be late so make sure you dispose it manually when you no longer need it)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this:
Define a class RPictures, which inherits List of RPicture and then simply override the 'Remove'-Function.

```
public class RPicture
{
    public Image Image;
    public string FilePath;
}

public class RPictures : Dictionary<RPicture>
{
    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        this[key].Image.Dispose();
        this.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity wouldn't the conversion from Dict to List make searching by key a bit difficult ? ;)

Comment: Oops, didn't see this. Thank you. ;)